# Problem 4.3.1 from Dummit and Foote.

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose that $G$ has a left action on a set $A$ denoted by $g\cdot a$. Denote the corresponding right action by $\sim'$.

So $a\sim b \Leftrightarrow a=gb for \ some \ g\in G$
And:

$a\sim^{'} b\Leftrightarrow a=bg \ for \ some\ g\in G$.

How to show then that there's equivalence bettween the two?

I need to show that $a\sim b \Leftrightarrow a\sim'b$

Clueless, really.
I need to show that there exists $h\in G$ s.t $a=bh$, I thought of using $a\sim b$ which means there exist: $g\in G$ s.t $a=gb$, but how to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed the text before the exercise.
For a left action $g\cdot a$, the *corresponding* right action $a* g$ is defined by $a* g=g^{-1} \cdot a$. (I use $\cdot$ and $*$ for left and right action respectively to avoid confusion.)

Using this definition, we can show that if $a\sim b$, then $a=g\cdot b$ for some $g\in G$, which implies $b=g^{-1}\cdot a=a* g$. Therefore $a=b* g^{-1}$ and we conclude that $a\sim' b$. The converse follows in the similar way.